# Memory Leak in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, robotframework

I am working with RF.
When I have 2 resource files with same name of Variables (but different in value). Each resource file has Method to log the current variable.
My problem is with the test cases, this test case import 2 resource files. When this test case do the method of the 2nd resource. It takes the data of the 1st resource. How this happen?

Code:

**Resource1.resource**

```
*** Variables ***
${VAR1}     Test 1
${VAR2}     Test 2


*** Keywords ***
Log The Var 1 1
    Log To Console    ${VAR1}

Log The Var 2 1
    Log To Console    ${VAR2}
```

**Resource2.resource**

```
*** Variables ***
${VAR1}     Test 3
${VAR2}     Test 3


*** Keywords ***
Log The Var 1 2
    Log To Console    ${VAR1}

Log The Var 2 2
    Log To Console    ${VAR2}
```

**Test.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../resources/Resource1.resource
Resource    ../resources/Resource2.resource

*** Test Cases ***
Test The Dup Thing

    Log The Var 1 1
    Log The Var 2 1

    Log The Var 1 2
    Log The Var 2 2
```

=> Output:
Test 1
Test 2
Test 1
Test 2

I don't know how this happen, seem like memory leak.

Comment: What do you mean by "memory leak"?

Comment: @tadman In java, you have private/public to isolate your method/variable. This RF does not have, so the problem is 2 methods use the same variable data. So I called this is a memory leak.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but be aware that [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) already means a very specific thing.